# Get all records that matches a specific criteria of another records over multiple partitions in the table

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, oracle12c, partitioning

I have the following view/table T:

```
+--------+--------------+-------+----------+
| row_id | batch_status | class | batch_id |
+--------+--------------+-------+----------+
| 1      | new          | K1    | B1       |
+--------+--------------+-------+----------+
| 2      | proc         | K1    | B2       |
+--------+--------------+-------+----------+
| 3      | proc         | K1    | B3       |
+--------+--------------+-------+----------+
| 4      | proc         | K1    | B1       |
+--------+--------------+-------+----------+
| 5      | finish       | K1    | B1       |
+--------+--------------+-------+----------+
| 6      | new          | K2    | B5       |
+--------+--------------+-------+----------+
| 7      | proc         | K2    | B2       |
+--------+--------------+-------+----------+
| 8      | new          | K3    | B2       |
+--------+--------------+-------+----------+
| 9      | proc         | K3    | B5       |
+--------+--------------+-------+----------+
| 10     | finish       | K3    | B1       |
+--------+--------------+-------+----------+
| 11     | finish       | K3    | B2       |
+--------+--------------+-------+----------+
| 12     | new          | K4    | B7       |
+--------+--------------+-------+----------+
| 13     | new          | K5    | B2       |
+--------+--------------+-------+----------+
```

where records are distributed over 5 classes: `k1 -> k5`.

Now **for each of those class groups** I need to display batches with ids that matches the `batch_id` of that one with status `'new'`. that's means what need to be **excluded** is (*red crossline*).
records those not striked-through are ones need to be displayed:

[image]

RDBMS: Oracle 12c

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Show your current code please.

Comment: So you want new and finish, not just new?

Comment: @Gnqz, No, OP wants rows with `batch_id`  = those of  the row where `batch_status`='new' of the same `class`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it:
Select this row if there exists, in the same table, a row with the same batch_id and class and batch_status=new.

```
Select *
From T as T1
Where
Exists (select 1
From T as T2
Where T2.batch_status='new'
And T2.batch_id=T1.batch_id
And T2.class=T1.class)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COUNT() OVER ()` analytic function with conditional in order to check the existence for any `batch_status` equals to the value `new` per each `class` and `batch_id` such as

```sql
SELECT row_id, batch_status, class, batch_id
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
               COUNT(CASE
                       WHEN batch_status = 'new' THEN
                        1
                     END) OVER(PARTITION BY class, batch_id) AS cnt
          FROM t)
 WHERE cnt > 0
 ORDER BY class
```

or without using a subquery(as your DB version is 12c)

```sql
SELECT t.*,
       COUNT(CASE
               WHEN batch_status = 'new' THEN
                    1
                END) OVER (PARTITION BY class, batch_id) AS cnt
  FROM t
 ORDER BY SIGN(cnt) DESC
 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW WITH TIES
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=58f328571650e7ebc2b65fc7f11033f0)</kbd>